# Is it possible to have a main `package.json` that receives an optional object of dependencies programatically?

Tags: npm, next.js, package.json, next.js13

I am pretty sure this might be tricky, but I haven't seen a good example of this before and am not sure how to tackle this.

This is a NextJS project that is effectively two applications in one let's call it projects `X` and `Y`.

There's the whole NextJS project with the `app` and `components` directories which include pages and components that are used by both project `X` and `Y` and behave the same way.

There are component directories which include components or values specific to the project. Say `@X` and `@Y`. These are included at build time depending on which project is being deployed.

The challenge here is to effectively do the same for Node dependencies, have some that are common between both projects but inject additional ones scoped to a specific project.

Let's say the app has the following dependencies in a single `package.json`:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^13.4.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
  }
```

Those dependencies are always installed for both projects, however I would like to have an additional file that installs dependencies for project `X` only:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  }
```

On build time the final `package.json` would be the following:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^13.4.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  }
```

Is a setup like this possible to achieve in any way?
Your thoughts would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Thanks Phil, doesn't answer it completely but it does help, it led me to NPM workspaces which might lead me down the right path.

Comment: I would like to have added a more detailed response but for some reason, the button to answer the question is not available. 

Looking at npm workspaces could help: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/workspaces?v=true